# virtual function, -> operator, inheritance SO CONFUSING

Tags: c++, function, pointers, inheritance, overriding

Ok this is a simple example that makes me so confused...

```
class First { public: void Func() {cout<<"FirstFunc";} };
class Second : public First
    { public: void Func() {cout<<"SecondFunc";} };
class Third : public Second
    { public: void Func() {cout<<"ThirdFunc";} };

int main () {
   Third * thirdptr = new Third();
   Second * secondptr = thirdptr;
   First * firstptr = secondptr;

   firstptr->Func();  // prints out FirstFunc
   secondptr->Func();  // prints out SecondFunc
   thirdptr->Func();  // prints out ThirdFunc

   delete thirdptr;
```

And this is with virtual function

```
class First { public: virtual void Func() {cout<<"FirstFunc";} };
class Second : public First
    { public: virtual void Func() {cout<<"SecondFunc";} };
class Third : public Second
    { public: virtual void Func() {cout<<"ThirdFunc";} };

int main () {
   Third * thirdptr = new Third();
   Second * secondptr = thirdptr;
   First * firstptr = secondptr;

   firstptr->Func();  // prints out ThirdFunc
   secondptr->Func();  // prints out ThirdFunc
   thirdptr->Func();  // prints out ThirdFunc

   delete thirdptr;
```

Ok, here is my question.

1. How do I read Third * thirdptr = new Third();
   new allocates a memory for int when "new int"
   but I have no clue how I am supposed to read new Third(); since it is constructor
2. Second * secondptr = thirdptr; / First * firstptr = secondptr;
   Those two statements are so confusing.
   Could anybody explain it with & operator or easy words relating it to address operator?
   I make sense of concept of this pointer and inheritance, but this part is so confusing.
3. How I am supposed to get the results from the second example?
   The book I am reading is saying

for first example
// C++ compiler regarding the pointer arithmetic operation, makes a decision
// based on the type of pointer, not on what the pointer is actually pointing to

for second example
// VIRTUAL FUNCTION : decide, not based on pointer type
//, what to call based on what the pointer is actually pointing to

This is translation, so might not be accurate, but still can't understand.
I would really appreciate it if you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `new Third()` does two things.  First it allocates memory for `Third` object and then it calls the constructor on `Third`.  You can think of the statement being in two parts, the `new Third` allocates memory and the `()` calls the constructor.
2. `Second * secondptr = thirdptr; / First * firstptr = secondptr;`  All three variables are assigned to the same pointer.  Let's say that `thritptr` equals 100.   Then both `secondptr` and `firstptr` will equal 100 at the end of these statments.  All three pointers point to the same address in memory.  However since they are different types they compiler iterprets them differents
3. For non-virtual functions the method calls are resolved at compile time, based on on the type of the variable.  So when compiling the first code `firstptr` is of type `First*` so the compiler generates a call to `First::Func()`.   For virtual functions, the method call isn't completely resolved until run time.  The compiler generates code which will determine the actual type that the variable points to and call that function.  In the second example, when the program runs, `firstpr->Func()` it first determines that `firstptr` really points to a `Thrird` object, so it calls `Third::Func()`.  This is normally done using a [virtual function table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, `new Third()` is, at a high level, doing the same thing as `new int`.  As you said, `new int` will allocate memory for an `int`, and the pointer on the left-hand side will point to that memory.  `new Third()` allocates memory for a `Third` object, and uses the default constructor of the `Third` class, `Third()`, to initialize it.

For you second question, you are creating three pointers and pointing them all to the same block of memory.  I believe because of the inheritance, it's possible to implicitly cast each pointer type to a higher type (implicit cast meaning without explicit instruction, such as `static_cast` or C-style cast).  Visually:

```
----
|  | <-- Some block of memory.
----

A -> ---- <-- A* aptr = new A();
     |  |
     ----

A -> ----
B -> |  | <-- B* bptr = aptr;
     ----

A -> ----
B -> |  |
C -> ---- <-- C* cptr = bptr;
```

Note how all three pointers point to the same block of memory.  (Also note that the pointers all point to the *start* of the memory - the exact same location.  It's difficult to portray that above.)

As for your third question:

> decide, not based on pointer type, what to call based on what the
>   pointer is actually pointing to

means that the compiler will decide which instance of the function to call based upon the actual type of the object in memory, rather than the type of the pointer that's pointing to the memory.  So, in your example, you created an object of type `Third`, and have three pointers pointing to it, of types `First`, `Second`, `Third`.  Regardless of the pointer type, though, because `Func` is virtual, `Third`'s version of `Func` is executed because the object in memory is of type `Third`.